# Geometry Node: Center Text On Face

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to center text on an arc by taking the mean value of the arc vertex positions and offsetting the position of text vertices with this value. But this doesn't seem to be working. What's going wrong?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before I get to the solution, this is just to show you what is going wrong with your setup: you have an *Arc* with *Resolution* of 16, that makes 17 points (including the origin point), and their positions are the cosine for X, sine for Y and Z is 0 for all of them.

Now you are plugging their *Position* values (a field of 17 vectors with 3 values each) into a *Float* input and calculate the *Mean*, which results in the *Attribute Statistic* node calculating the average value of 51 float values.

[image: points and average]

This single average float value of about 0.398 you then plug into the *Offset* input of the *Set Position* node, which expects vectors. Feeding it a single float results in using this value for X, Y and Z and so placing your text at (0.398, 0.398, 0.398). In your top view screenshot it looks like it's just misplaced in X and Y, but it's also placed above the arc:

[image: offset]

So to calculate the center of the area enclosed by the *Arc* (which is what I suppose you tried to achieve) you first of all have to choose *Vector* in the *Attribute Statistic* node. If you leave the *Domain* at *Point* you will end up having the text placed close to the curve on the right, since there are much more points than the only one to the left.

The same will occur if you choose *Edge*, what you need is *Face*. In order to make this work you have to plug a *Fill Curve* node after the *Arc* node. There are two settings: *N-gons* will get you the same result as *Point* or *Edge*, but *Triangles* will place it correctly.

You can compare this with setting the origin of a mesh object. If you right-click on it and go to *Set Origin* there are (among others) the options *Origin to Center of Mass (Surface)* and *Origin to Center of Mass (Volume)*. In the image below you see an orange outline, this is a mesh object in the shape of the *Arc* with the same number of vertices.

Choosing *Origin to Center of Mass (Surface)* sets the origin where the calculated *Mean* is with the *Triangles* option in the *Fill Curve* node, but using *N-gons* the *Mean* is where the *Origin to Center of Mass (Volume)* would be set and it is the same place you'll get with the *Point* option. (By the way, although it's still in my screenshot - since you don't want to move separate points of the text curve, a *Realize Instances* node is not needed).

[image: center of mass surface vs volume]

The only problem that's left is this might not really look correctly placed - when you look at the orange origin points in the above image, the character "a" seems a bit off-center, and comparing to uppercase "H" or "O" you can see it's not only because it's lowercase. Since fonts have so called *ascenders* and *descenders*, the center of a character is often not the visible center of its geometry.

To get the center of the character's geometry you can plug it into a *Bounding Box* node (after *Realizing Instances*) and calculate the *Mean* like you do with the *Arc*. Then subtract the character's *Mean* from the *Arc's Mean* and use this as _Offset for the *Set Position* node:

[image: bounding box offset]

This results in better placed characters as you can see below. You can use either the *Bounding Box* as I showed in the nodetree above or the *Convex Hull* node. For very symmetrical letters like the uppercase "H" and "O" it won't make a difference, however if you have an asymmetrical letter like the lowercase "a" it will slightly differ.

[image: bounding box centered]

At last here is a comparison with the character "a" and using *Bounding Box* vs. *Convex Hull*. As you can see, there is a very subtle difference and it might not matter much, however with other characters or even words instead of single characters it might look different. I guess it's mostly dependent on the shapes and an aesthetical decision based on your preferences which one you choose, I just wanted to show you the options.

[image: bounding box vs convex hull]

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed explanation!

Comment: @LomaHarshana The only problem here is that font characters usually don't have their center in the center of the actual curve that builds the letter. If you took a small circle for example and would place it with this setup inside the arc, you will see that the letters are slightly offset from this. To place a character centered according to its geometry you have to use a _Bounding Box_ or _Convex Hull_ node. I will edit my answer to show this.

Comment: Such a good answer. Mine was based on 'largest circle that can be inscribed'... but too complicated for this  case.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thanks again!

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I have a quick side question, if you don't mind (please ignore it if it doesn't make sense). In your first illustration, where you have shown the arc vertices and their angles, how did you add the angle values for so many vertices with correct alignment?

Comment: @LomaHarshana "simple" manual placing in Photoshop :D

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Amazing skills. Really appreciate your efforts in answering the question so thoroughly.